# Unable to install Ruby MySQL Gem on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, ruby

When attempting to install the Ruby MySQL Gem on Mac OS X:

```
# ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/mysql-2.9.1/mkmf.log
find_library: checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... -------------------- no
```

Similar messages about the same missing function throughout mkmf.log.

I assume missing dependencies but I don't know what they would be or where this would be documented. Google doesn't seem to help. And the project is unmaintained.

Tried Ruby 2.1.4, 2.2.7, 2.4.1.

Comment: Did you check if you have the `lmysqlclient` dependency installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the `mysqlclient` library installed. The easiest way to get it on your machine is to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and do `brew install mysql`.

The `mysql` gem has native extensions - that is, when the gem is installed, native parts of it are compiled. You will need a C/C++ toolchain as well on your Mac for this to work. If you have XCode installed, you should be good to go as it provides clang.